# How to play VideoView inside of a PopUp window

Tags: android, android-studio, android-videoview, popupwindow

Hey everyone so I am having a problem with a videoView inside of a popUp window, everytime I try open the window it shuts down the app for some reason. I know where is the problem but I dont know the correct way to fix the issue. If anyone knows how to fix this it would be much appriacated.

This is my main activity

```
   public class Day1 extends AppCompatActivity {
      Dialog myDialog;

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.part_sh_day1);

           myDialog = new Dialog(this);
}
   public void ShowFirstPopup(View v) {
        TextView mTextView;

        //================================-Text-View-====================================

        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.video_popup);
        mTextView = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.txtclose);
        mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //================================-Video-View-====================================

        VideoView mVideoView;
        mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.gymsharktrain_1);


        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.show();

        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
   }
}
```

And this is the xml file op popUp window

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@color/colorGrey"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtclose"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey"
        android:text="X"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/circlebackground"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error messege:

2020-01-15 21:57:59.138 3179-3224/com.example..... D/IMonitor: Load library imonitor_jni
2020-01-15 21:57:59.140 3179-3179/com.example..... V/ActivityThread: Skipping new config:{1.0 231mcc2mnc [en_GB] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h679dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2037) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 81 - 1080, 2118) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} nonFullScreen=0 suim:1 s.22}, config:{1.0 231mcc2mnc [en_GB] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h679dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2037) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 81 - 1080, 2118) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} nonFullScreen=0 suim:1 s.22} for app:com.example.......
2020-01-15 21:57:59.142 3179-3207/com.example..... E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2020-01-15 21:57:59.148 3179-3224/com.example.....W/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: Failed to get config from zrhung
2020-01-15 21:57:59.164 3179-3222/com.example..... E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@1093b93
2020-01-15 21:57:59.191 3179-3179/com.example..... V/HwPolicyFactory: : success to get AllImpl object and return....
2020-01-15 21:57:59.195 3179-3179/com.example..... V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
        at com.example......ShowFirstPopup

Comment: Please grab the stacktrace from logcat and post it here.

Comment: @greeble31 Updated. (Posted)

Comment: @greeble31 so if I understand it correctly, I am deferencing mVideoView after creating an activity where the object uri is not declared and that causes a NullPointerException. So I should either create an if statement where if uri == null then do something or just simply move the declaration under myDialog.show();.                        Is that correct?

Comment: No - it is `mVideoView` that is null. You are trying to call `setVideoURI()`  "on a null object reference".

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and run the app in debug mode, it will really help you out.

Comment: Incidentally you might be able to fix this by calling `myDialog.findViewById()` instead of calling it on your `Activity` (`Activity.findViewById()` will not search dialogs; it only searches the `Activity` content).

Comment: @greeble31 would you please be that kind and write an example of what should I write because I dont know why its so confusing for me but I cant see the solution for this problem.

Comment: Take the line `mVideoView = findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);` and replace it with `mVideoView = mDialog.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);`.

Comment: @greeble31 Of course that makes sence! Wonderful, thank you.